# Handle async on firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am trying to initiaze each calendar cell with a color that is based on some info on my firebase database and for that I use a flag which is set as false and then it becomes true if the conditions are met. The thing is that the addListenerForSingleValueEvent is an async method so the flag returns all the time as false. How should I handle it?

```
mCalendar.addDecorator(new DayViewDecorator() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldDecorate(final CalendarDay day) {
                    final boolean[] flag = {false};
                    final String currentDate = day.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR)
                            + "" + day.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH)
                            + "" + day.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    database.child(currentDate).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                flag[0] = true;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                    return flag[0];
                }

                @Override
                public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
                    view.addSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.material_red_a200)));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, move the declaration of your `boolean[] flag` array inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise it will be always null.

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    final boolean[] flag = {false};
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        flag[0] = true;
    }
    Log.d("TAG", flag[0]);
}
```

This is happening due the asynchronous behaviour of `onDataChange()` method, which is called before even you are trying to get the value from that array.
Moving the declaration inside the method and using it also there, solves your problem.

If you want to use the value of that array outside that method, please take a look at my answer from this post, [How To Get Async Value Outside onDataChange() Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I cant move the flag there because I need to return it. I know that the return statement is useless when I have the onDataChange but I can not change the UI unless a return happens. I use the mCalendar.addDecorator(new DayViewDecorator()) which first goes to the shouldDecorate method and after the return it goes to the decorate method so I need a boolean return. Sorry if I am not understanding you completely

Comment: In this case, you need to change the logic of your code flow to use it inside that method. Or try to use it outside that method, as explained in my above post.

Comment: I also thought to use the onDataChange inside the decorate method but that is not possible because I need the "day" variable from the previous method. Is there any way to execute the return after I get the value from the DB? I saw on solution using Bus but it did not help much.

Comment: No, there is not. There only two ways. One way is to declare it and use it insdide and the second way is to use it outisde using that interface in my example.

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I see that I can solve it with RxJava

Comment: Did my answer helped you in any way?